# Loop through checkboxes in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox, userform

I'm trying to create a code to loop through a userform to see if the checkboxes are checked and then create a PDF of the sheets.
However I get the error "object doesn't support this property or method" in the line "If ctl.controlFormat.Value = True Then". I hope you can help me :)

```
     Option Explicit


Sub Get_PDF_Click()

Dim ReportName As String
ReportName = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 20).Value
Dim OutputPath As String
OutputPath = "T:\5. Fælles\Optima Lancering Version 1.0\6. Oversigtsark\KontoInvest\Historik\"
Dim YYMM As String
Dim Name_of_File As String
Dim Name As String
'Dim x1TypePDF As Variant
Dim cbox As CheckBox
Dim FormControlType As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
'Dim shp As Shape

YYMM = Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now(), -1), "YYMM")

Name = "BankNordik_faktaark" & YYMM
Name_of_File = OutputPath & "BankNordik\" & Name

 '------- LOOP THROUGH CHECKBOXES -------
For i = 0 To 6
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    'For Each ctl In PDFUserForm.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        'If ctl.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
            If ctl.ControlFormat.Value = True Then
                    For Each Ws In Worksheets
                        If Ws.Name = "Fakta " & Kunde_Array(i + 1, 1) Then
                            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                            Name_of_File, Quality _
                            :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                            :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
                        End If
                    Next Ws
             End If
        End If
    Next ctl
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line is the error? • Remove `Dim x1TypePDF As Variant` and replace `Type:=x1TypePDF` with `Type:=xlTypePDF` Note that `xl` is a lower case `XL` not `X1` • Also avoid `Variant` if possible, it's the worst type you could choose: `YYMM`, `Name_of_File`, and `Name` could be declared as `String`. • Since you use `Option Explicit` your code should throw an error if you don't declare `i As Long`. • `Kunde_Array` isn't declared neither, so get your variables clean and declare everything.

Comment: It is in the line "For each shp in PDFUserForm" :) and thank you. I still get the error though :/ @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Please [edit] your question and update the code to what you have now after you applied my suggestions. Note that you `Dim PDFUserForm As UserForm` but `PDFUserForm` is never set to something. Therefore `PDFUserForm` is `Nothing`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I  have edited the question. Also i and kundearray are defined public in another module.

Comment: What would you set PDFUserForm to @Pᴇʜ? :) :) :) and

Comment: @Therese ehhhm to your desired UserForm of course? • If `PDFUserForm` is already the name of your UserForm just remove `Dim PDFUserForm As UserForm`.

Comment: Don't you need to loop through controls? -> `Dim shp As Control` and `For Each shp In Me.Controls`

Comment: @JvdV I just edited the code and the error in my post :)

Comment: @Therese `FormControlType` is only for `Shapes`. Since you changed it to `Control` you must use `If TypeName(shp) = "CheckBox" Then`. Also consider changing the variable name from `shp` to `ctl` to stop confusing yourself about the type of that variable.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ THANK YOU :) now I get another error though, see my edited post.

Comment: @Therese oh come on you should start doing some research and reading the documentations. I cannot fix all the code for you. A `CheckBox` object doesn't have a `.ControlFormat`.